# nullpointexception:error while inserting data into firebase database

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

i have provided a intent from the registration page to the add contacts page and in the add contacts page tried to add the details into the firebase database using two functions addusers() and addcontacts()
can somebody pls help me

this is my registration.java file

```
package universe.sk.syndriveapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class RegistrationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText etName, etEmailsign, etPassign, etConfirmPassign, etBloodgroup, etDate;
    private Button btn_register;
    private TextView tvExist;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    String name, email, password, bloodgrp, date;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("SIGN UP");
        setupUIViews();

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        btn_register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (validate()) {
                    String user_email = etEmailsign.getText().toString().trim();
                    String user_password = etPassign.getText().toString().trim();

                    //store in database:to be done after filling the contacts
                    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user_email, user_password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                finish();
                                startActivity(new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, AddContacts.class));
                                //Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Registration Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else
                                Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Registration Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });


                    //startActivity(new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this,NavigationActivity.class));
                }
            }
        });

        tvExist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }


    private void setupUIViews() {
        etName = findViewById(R.id.etName);
        etEmailsign = findViewById(R.id.etEmailsign);
        etPassign = findViewById(R.id.etPassign);
        btn_register = findViewById(R.id.btn_register);
        tvExist = findViewById(R.id.tvExist);
        etConfirmPassign = findViewById(R.id.etConfirmPassign);
        etDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDate);
        etBloodgroup = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etBloodgroup);
    }

    private Boolean validate() {
        Boolean result = false;
        bloodgrp = etBloodgroup.getText().toString().trim();
        date = etDate.getText().toString().trim();
        name = etName.getText().toString();
        password = etPassign.getText().toString();
        email = etEmailsign.getText().toString();
        String confirmpass = etConfirmPassign.getText().toString();

        if (name.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty() || email.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter all the details!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            if (password.equals(confirmpass))
                result = true;
            else
                Toast.makeText(this, "Confirm password doesn't match with your password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return result;

    }
}
```

this is my addcontacts java file

```
package universe.sk.syndriveapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;


public class AddContacts extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button registerbtn;
     EditText etName,etEmailsign,etPassign,etBloodgroup,etDate;
    EditText name1, num1, name2, num2, name3, num3;
    String emname1,emname2,emname3;
    String emnum1,emnum2,emnum3;
    String name,email,password,bloodgrp,date;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_addcontacts);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.contacts);
        actionBar.setTitle(" Add Emergency Contacts");
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        registerbtn= findViewById(R.id.registerbtn);

        name1 = findViewById(R.id.name1);
        num1 = findViewById(R.id.num1);

        name2 = findViewById(R.id.name2);
        num2 = findViewById(R.id.num2);
        name3 = findViewById(R.id.name3);
        num3 = findViewById(R.id.num3);
        setupUIViews();
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        registerbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int value=checkData();
                if(value==1) {
                    emname1 = name1.getText().toString();
                    emnum1 = num1.getText().toString();
                    emname2 = name2.getText().toString();
                    emnum2 = num2.getText().toString();
                    emname3 = name3.getText().toString();
                    emnum3 = num3.getText().toString();
                    bloodgrp = etBloodgroup.getText().toString().trim();
                    date = etDate.getText().toString().trim();
                    name = etName.getText().toString();
                    password = etPassign.getText().toString();
                    email = etEmailsign.getText().toString();
                    adduser();
                    addcontacts();

                /*
                if (emname1.isEmpty() || emname2.isEmpty() || emname3.isEmpty()){
                    startActivity(new Intent(AddContacts.this, RegistrationActivity.class));
                    Toast.makeText(AddContacts.this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                */

                    Toast.makeText(AddContacts.this, "Registration Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(AddContacts.this, NavigationActivity.class));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    boolean isEmpty(EditText text){
        CharSequence str = text.getText().toString();
        return TextUtils.isEmpty(str);
    }

    int checkData(){
                if(isEmpty(name1) || isEmpty(name2) || isEmpty(name3) || isEmpty(num1) || isEmpty(num2) || isEmpty(num3)){
                    Toast.makeText(AddContacts.this,"Please fill all contact details",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return -1;
                }
                else
                    return 1;
            }


    private void setupUIViews()
    {
        etName = findViewById(R.id.etName);
        etEmailsign = findViewById(R.id.etEmailsign);
        etPassign = findViewById(R.id.etPassign);

        etDate =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etDate);
        etBloodgroup =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etBloodgroup);
    }
    private void addcontacts(){
        FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference databaseusers = firebaseDatabase.getReference(firebaseAuth.getUid());
        Contactdetails contactdetails;
        contactdetails = new Contactdetails(emname1,emname2,emname3,emnum1,emnum2,emnum3);
        databaseusers.setValue(contactdetails);
    }
    private void adduser(){
        FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference databaseusers= firebaseDatabase.getReference(firebaseAuth.getUid());
        Userinfo user;
        user = new Userinfo(name,email,date,bloodgrp);
        databaseusers.setValue(user);

    }
}
```

this is my userinfo java file

```
package universe.sk.syndriveapp;

import android.net.Uri;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

public class Userinfo {
    public String username;
    public String uemail;
    public String udate;
    public String bloodgroup;
    // public Uri imageUri;
    public Userinfo(){

    }

    public Userinfo(String username, String uemail, String udate, String bloodgroup) {
        this.username = username;
        this.uemail = uemail;
        this.udate = udate;
        this.bloodgroup = bloodgroup;
        // this.imageUri = imageUri;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getUemail() {
        return uemail;
    }
    public void setUemail(String uemail) {
        this.uemail = uemail;
    }

    public String getUdate(){
        return udate;
}
    public void setUdate(String udate) {
        this.udate = udate;
    }

    public String getBloodgroup() {
        return bloodgroup;
    }
    public void setBloodgroup(String bloodgroup) {
        this.bloodgroup = bloodgroup;
    }

    /* public Uri getImageUri() {
        return imageUri;
    }
    public void setImageUri(Uri imageUri) {
        this.imageUri = imageUri;
    } */
}
```

this is my contactdetails java file

```
package universe.sk.syndriveapp;

public class Contactdetails {
    public String cname1;
    public  String cname2;
    public String cname3;
    public String no1;
    public String no2;
    public String no3;

    public Contactdetails(){

    }

    public Contactdetails(String cname1, String cname2, String cname3, String no1, String no2, String no3) {
        this.cname1 = cname1;
        this.cname2 = cname2;
        this.cname3 = cname3;
        this.no1 = no1;
        this.no2 = no2;
        this.no3 = no3;
    }

    public void setCname1(String cname1) {
        this.cname1 = cname1;
    }

    public void setCname2(String cname2) {
        this.cname2 = cname2;
    }

    public void setCname3(String cname3) {
        this.cname3 = cname3;
    }

    public void setNo1(String no1) {
        this.no1 = no1;
    }

    public void setNo2(String no2) {
        this.no2 = no2;
    }

    public void setNo3(String no3) {
        this.no3 = no3;
    }

    public String getCname1() {
        return cname1;
    }

    public String getCname2() {
        return cname2;
    }

    public String getCname3() {
        return cname3;
    }

    public String getNo1() {
        return no1;
    }

    public String getNo2() {
        return no2;
    }

    public String getNo3() {
        return no3;
    }
}
```

this is my addcontacts xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/hint_emname1"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/num1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/hint_num1"
            android:inputType="phone" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/hint_emname2"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/num2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/hint_num2"
            android:inputType="phone" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/hint_emname3"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/num3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/hint_num3"
            android:inputType="phone" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/registerbtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="@string/hint_registerbtn"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
</LinearLayout>
```

this is my profile xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".RegistrationActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/user_name"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.106" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etDate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/date_of_birth"
            android:inputType="date" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etBloodgroup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/blood_group"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etEmailsign"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etDate" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etPassign"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etEmailsign"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.08" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etConfirmPassign"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/confirm_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etPassign"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.08" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_register"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="@string/next"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etConfirmPassign"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.132" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvExist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Already an existing member? Login"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_register" />
</LinearLayout>
```

finally this is my error log

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
    at universe.sk.syndriveapp.AddContacts$1.onClick(AddContacts.java:67)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5619)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22295)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6237)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: Both answers are trying to tell you that you can only find views from the XML file set by setContentView for that current Activity

Comment: so ill have to enter details seperately?? like one half in registration activity and other n add contacts ? i tried doing tht but the details entered in the firebase database by the registration activity gets overwritten by the details in add contacts any soln for tht??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
bloodgrp = etBloodgroup.getText().toString().trim();
```

causes the error.

You haven't done a `findViewById()` on the `EditText` *bloodgroup* before and it also does not exist in the `addcontacts.xml` file. If you have defined it in another xml file, you won't be able to call it in an `Activity` not associated with the xml source (and you cannot associate more than one xml layout file to an `Activity`).

So the answer is basically: **Define the `EditText` in the xml file associated to the `Activity` where you are trying to handle it.**

Comment: i have called a setupuiviews func which sets up the views

Comment: Ok, I missed that one... But it still stays the same error line and the `EditText` is `null`...

Comment: yea thts why i am confused

Comment: can we take views from two xml files in a java file

Comment: No, you cannot... Every `Activity` or `Fragment` must have its own xml file (as far as I know)

Answer (score 1):

Your `addcontacts.xml` doesn't have an `EditText` with ID *etBloodgroup*

Comment: But you're doing bloodgrp = etBloodgroup.getText().toString().trim(); on the AddContacts activity!

Comment: i have taken the views from both the xml files is that possible sry i am new to this

Comment: No. you will need to put another EditText on the addcontact.xml with that ID